# helm unable to initialize variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using helm.In this i want to create manifest file as below syntax in Annotations

```
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-sourcedetails: |
          {{ with secret  /dmw-mysql/kv2/postgres/semarchy/abc.postgres.database.azure.com   -}}
          {{ .Data.data.semarchy_dloc1 }}
          {{- end }}
```

I used helm code but it is not evaluating second line variable to value.Not sure where am doing wrong.
helm template demotest

```
          {{ printf "{{ with secret "}} {{ .Values.vault.path }}/{{ .Values.serversdetails.dbsourcedetails.hostname }}  {{ ` -}} 
          {{ .Data.data.{{ .Values.serversdetails.dbsourcedetails.pgusername }} }}
          {{- end }} `}}
```

But this is printing output .it is not evaluating second line variable to value when i use

```
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-sourcedetails: |
          {{ with secret  /dmw-mysql/kv2/postgres/semarchy/abc.postgres.database.azure.com  -}}
          {{  .Data.data.{{ .Values.serversdetails.dbsourcedetails.hostname }}   }}
          {{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing Helm template code that needs to include Go template constructs or otherwise the special `{{` character sequence, I'd recommend using a specific syntax where you need it

```
{{ "{{" }}
```

Your file has a mix of `printf` calls and backtick escaping.  You want Helm to expand the `{{ .Values... }}` expression, but it's inside a backtick-quoted string, so Helm doesn't evaluate it.

Taking your desired output, replacing open-double-curly-braces, and inserting the one Helm expression, I'd write

```yaml
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-sourcedetails: |
  {{ "{{" }} with secret  /dmw-mysql/kv2/postgres/semarchy/abc.postgres.database.azure.com   -}}
  {{ "{{" }}.Data.data.{{ .Values.serversdetails.dbsourcedetails.hostname }}}}
  {{ "{{" }}- end }}
```

Look carefully at this to see what parts are and aren't in `{{ ... }}` blocks; those are what Helm will evaluate and substitute.